# Blocked DLL Detected: MySQL because of No-Installation Download

Tags: mysql, dll, zip, unzip, blocked

This error keeps on appearing whenever I try to create a new schema.

I can't quite understand the instructions. I went to my specified SQL folder but what "zip- unzip" was the instruction talking about? Moreover, it didn't specify what DLL should I look for.

I hope someone can help! Thanks!

[image: This error keeps on appearing whenever I try to create a new schema.]

Answer (score 1):

You could try to run the MySQL Workbench as Administrator, than it can possibly unblock the dlls automatically.

If not, g to the folder where you have installed MySQL Workbench and use the Explorer Search functionality to search for all *.dll and *.exe. Then right click on each. If the dll/exe is blocked, you see an unblock button on the properties page, press it. You have to repeat this for all dlls/exes.